# Second derivative of a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, minimal-surfaces

I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6597), in which the author considers a geodesic $\gamma(t)$ on a surface with $\gamma(0)=p,\gamma'(0)=v, \|v\|=1$ and wants to express the second derivative.

He gets
$$\gamma''(t) = - \gamma(t) - h(\gamma',\gamma')\nu(\gamma(t)),$$
where $\nu$ is the gauss map and $h$ is the Weingarten map/Second fundamental form.
I see how he gets the first part, but i can't see how he gets the normal part. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it the paper by Brendle?

Comment: Yes, the paper by Brendle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we have

$$\gamma \subset \Sigma \subset \mathbb S^3 \subset \mathbb R^4.$$

and $\gamma$ is a geodesic in $\Sigma$. Let $\nabla$ be the connection on $\Sigma$. Then $\nabla_{\gamma'} \gamma'=0$. By definition of $\nabla$, it's

$$\nabla_{ \gamma'} \gamma' = \gamma'' - (\gamma'')^\perp,$$

where $(v)^\perp$ denote the part $v$ which is orthogonal to $T\Sigma$. Since $(T\Sigma)^\perp$ is spanned by $\nu, \gamma$, we have

$$
(\gamma'')^\perp = \langle \gamma'' , \gamma\rangle \gamma + \langle \gamma'', \nu\rangle \nu.  
$$

Firstly, since $\langle \gamma, \gamma\rangle=1$, differentiate twice gives

$$\langle \gamma '', \gamma\rangle = - \langle \gamma', \gamma'\rangle = -\|v\| 
 =-1.$$

Second, $\langle\gamma'',  \nu\rangle = h(\gamma',\gamma')$. Thus

$$\gamma''= (\gamma'')^\perp = - \gamma + h(\gamma', \gamma') \nu$$

I am somehow missing a sign. Probably because Brendle is using $h(\gamma',\gamma') := \langle \gamma', \nabla_{\gamma'} \nu\rangle$?

Comment: The standard sign convention, yes, is that $h(V,W)=-\langle\nabla_V\nu,W\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i see where my mistake was.